# Microsoft Teams won't open some Excel files in desktop app

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, microsoft, teams

Recently I've noticed that several Excel files cannot be opened any longer when opening them from within Teams. When I click the file, the file opens in Teams, but as soon as I try to open the file by clicking "open in desktop app", an error appears after Excel has started. The exact error is: "(filename) cannot be opened", followed by another dialog stating several possible reasons (which are not the case).

When I log on to the computer as another user who is a (recent) member of the same team, I can open the file just fine.

I've tried the following steps to mitigate the problem:

- Checked the permissions of the file (but they are the same for both users)
- Updated the Teams version
- Reinstalled Teams
- Reinstalled Teams after removing the %appdata%\Microsoft\Teams directory
- Reinstalled Microsoft Office

Each time followed by a reboot, but each time without any effect, the Excel file still won't open.

The strange thing is: when I rename the file, the file opens fine. When I rename it back to the original name, the file continues to be opened fine in the desktop app...

I have the impression that Excel keeps some sort of cache, which gets invalidated by renaming the file, but I don't know whether or not that is true, or how to clear that cache.

Has anybody encountered this issue yet, and does anybody know of a fix for this?

My Teams version is 1.5.00.21668
My Office version is 2208 (build 15601.20148 Klik-en-Klaar) (which translates to "click-and-ready")

Comment: Not quite the same - I've found Teams doesn't always open the Excel file in the desktop app, but it does add it to the Most Recently Used list and I can open it from there, or I can navigate to the file location in Excel and open it.  No idea why it doesn't open from Teams though.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue on what’s likely SharePoint, contact your system Administrator, for assistance

Comment: @Ramhound: unfortunately, I am the system administrator...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.

In my case, I linked the Sharepoint related to this Teams Team with OneDrive, and trying to open the file (downloaded on the computer through OneDrive) throws the same error. If I copy this downloaded file to another local location, like C:\Temp, it works

Update:
I tried the same action logging on another computer and it worked, so I'm deleting the user profile on the original computer. After that, it's solved for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).